# Setting up a project in Xcode for "Assembly Language"

Tags: assembly

SITUATION:

For my microcontroller class I am using a microcontroller "HCS12" from the vendor "Freescale". I've been advised in using their IDE called Code Warrior. I would like to use Xcode to write in Assembly Code doing away with Code Warrior completely. If the Xcode executable file and the HCS12 are incapadible I would still like to know how to setup a project so I can at the very least practice writing code in Assembly language. Even though I've used Xcode before with C++ I would still consider myself a beginner so If you could be clear in explaining your instructions or guidance I would appreciate it.

QUESTIONS:

Question 1:

How do I set up a project file and template file to start coding in Assembly language?

I have searched for instructions on this and i've seen so many ways that I'm confused now. The way I have done it is mentioned below. Could someone advise me in the more common or perhaps correct way in setting up a project and template file to start coding in Assembly.

The way I ended up doing it was explained at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/567682. This was not my discussion, it was just something that popped up in a google search. There were many things explained in this discussion. I got very confused and ended up picking one option which was the instruction set posted by "Mark Szymczyk".

1. Created an "External Build System
2. Name it test1
3. Under build tool I entered the following direction "/usr/bin/as."
4. I added a new file template called "assembly .s"

Question 2:

What is the build tool field mean? I changed it over to "/usr/bin/as" and forgot what exactly it was before I changed it. I would like to know what I just changed in case I have to change it back to what it was before. I think it was previously set as usr/bin/build or something similar. The only thing I have learned about this is from what i've gathered through navigating to it from terminal. I see a ton of files and directories under bin. I see that the file "as" is just a file and I have opened it in vi. But I just get a mess of encrypted data.

Question 3:

If I do this in Xcode will I be able to upload my executable file to the HCS12 microcontroller?

Will I need to create an executable file or is the file I'm already writing my code in ".s"  my executable file? I think it is my source code file but I'm confused if a source file and executable file are two different files and how I'm suppose to generate an executable file.

Will there be a compadability error between my execuatble file and the HCS12 microcontroller to where it will not upload correctly? If this is the case I will have to revert to using Code Warrior.

Thanks:

Like I mentioned at the top I would at the very least like to know how to setup a project to code in assembly language in Xcode. Therefore, your guidance and instruction is greatly appriciated in clearing up my confusion.